# Idangero Sniper: Add a slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a lazy loading slide within an ajax call but don't known why the image is not showing up

```
mySwiper.appendSlide(['<div class="swiper-slide"><img data-src="blabla.jpg" class="swiper-lazy"></div>']);
setTimeout(function () { mySwiper.update(); },500);
mySwiper.lazy.load( mySwiper.slides.length -1 );
mySwiper.slideTo(mySwiper.slides.length -1,500,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the DOM instead

```
$(".swiper-wrapper div:last-child").after('<div class="swiper-slide"><img data-src="blabla.jpg" class="swiper-lazy"></div>');
setTimeout(function () { mySwiper.update(); },500);
mySwiper.slideTo(mySwiper.slides.length -1,500,false);
```